# Relative error and contaminated digits

Tags: floating-point

On page 9 of [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/551.jvn.fall01/goldberg.pdf) it says

> When only the order of magnitude of rounding error is of interest, ulps and e may be used interchangeably since they differ by at most a factor of b. For example, when a floating-point number is in error by n ulps, that means the number of contaminated digits is log_b n. If the relative error in a computation is n*e, then
>
> contaminated digits = log_b n.

When the error is n ulps I can fill in the details to get log_b n contaminated digits. But what are the details for the last sentence about relative error?

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. What details do you want?

Comment: I simply don't see why its true.

Answer (score 2):

It is only an approximation. ε is defined as the largest relative error that half an  ULP can be. From its definition on page 8, we can see that it can range from 1/2 ULP to β/2 ULP. Although it varies considerably, it has the same order of magnitude as an ULP.

Since the “number of contaminated digits” with an error of *n* ULPs is log<sub>β</sub> *n*, then it is about the same when there is an error of *n*ε. As the text states, this is only an order-of-magnitude approximation.

(Goldberg’s paper is loose on some points, such as making an order-of-magnitude approximation and labeling error as “number of contaminated digits”. Even a slight error can change any number of digits, as when adding one causes a sequence of nines (in decimal) to roll over to zeros. The “number of contaminated digits” is a description of the size of the error, not the actual number of changed digits.)

Comment: It's too bad there's no common notation for writing a number with a "10" in the last digit [so that if a value is known to be greater than 9/10 but less than one, one could write the first digit after the decimal point as 9, then if greater than 99/100 but less than unity, one could write the next digit as nine, etc.]

Comment: So do you mean that since ε corresponds to the maximum relative error of 1/2 ULP, then n*ε corresponds to n/2 ULP. Then as a rough order of magnitude n/2 ULP is n ULP which corresponds to contaminated digits = log_b n. So n*ε corresponds to contaminated digits = log_b n